# Google map api v3 + Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Just came across this error today intermittently:

```
Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. See the Terms of Service for more information: http://www.google.com/intl/en-US_US/help/terms_maps.html.
```

somehow when I refresh the page, the map comes back again. I thought if it's a violation, it would have revoke the key permanently and not allow the map loads using this key anymore. Also, the error always happens at page load. I have yet to hit the error if it's already successfully loaded. I briefly read through the terms but couldn't find anything suspicious. Anyone can advise on how to go about this error? Should I be checking for some js error or the map terms? Thanks.

This is how the map script looks like:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&libraries=places&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" type="text/javascript"> </script>
```

Comment: Looks like it's fixed now (11:24am Sydney time, 13/02/2013)

Answer (score 4):

You could try the [documented URL](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API) for the maps API script:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE">
    </script>
```

Where key is recommended but not mandatory and sensor is required.

(so this should work):

```
<script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE">
    </script>
```

Comment: I have changed the URL as documented but still getting intermittent message, thing is, is google map actually able to "detect" violation of map usages on your site as I am not sure what to look into now, my program or the map regulations.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed the same issue this morning as well, I thought it was because I was using a subdomain of the domain registered with the API service, but it is happening to my actual domain as well.

I have removed the api key from the library url which seems to have fixed the problem for now, I will put it back when it starts working again. This must be an issue with Google's licensing servers since it is affecting their own websites as well.

Comment: Happened to us to. Removing key for now seems to work. Not ideal but works.